# Deploying nodejs to amazon

Tags: node.js, git, amazon-web-services

I'm new with NodeJS and have worked lately with a project which run in NodeJS. This project is actually going to be put online. The server runs on Amazon and is now running an "old" version of the project.

I've had a very fast manual how to deploy, but I didn't get it.

What I got:

1. Install cygwin (already did)
2. tar the project without the .git directory in cygwin
3. Upload the tar to the server in cygwin
4. Restart the application

Does anyone know a good tutorial or can someone explain to me how I do best? I know that there is no auto deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I recently setup a nodejs application on AWS, the tools that i used was

- nginx server for handling my http request, as starting nodejs in terminal is very problematic.
- pm2 for auto restarting nodejs in case if error occur
- git for version control, maintained a repo of my code and clone it to my AWS server
- SSH for remote login

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually in the same process of deploying a node server via amazon aws. I personally started with watching some Videos to get a clue about AWS EC2, S3 and so on. The following link is a good start for understand some conecpts:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jLVPqoV4YjU

afterwards it is best to read the documentation (better not all of it just the things you need and want to understand).

I also use pm2, git and maybe will use nginx also as reverse proxy ...